# query to print the data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have a list of tables as follows

```
tbluser
(userid, username)

tblmember
(memberid, fk_userid)

tblleader
(leaderid, fk_userid)

tbltask
(taskid, fk_memberid, fk_leaderid, taskname, taskstatus)
```

here the user will be a member and can be a leader too

i want to generate a query to show the list of the assigned task to the members and their leaders name.

```
Sl. No | Member Name | Task Name | Task Status | Leader Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am having joining issues as both member and leader table is referenced to the same table(user table).

Can anybody help me to get the query to show the data.

Comment: Hello sam, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please post a query attempt so that we can point you in the right direction? Please note that Stack Overflow is not a coding service. We are here to help you, but not to do your work for you. I can give you a hint though, you will need to use subqueries. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/ https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/subqueries/index.php

Answer (score 1):

You question wasn't clear enough ,but i think your looking for this.

```
SELECT taskname,taskstatus,username
FROM tbltask,tblmember,tblleader,tbuser
WHERE (tblmember.memberid = tbltask.fk_memberid) AND (tbltask.fk_leaderid = 
tblleader.leaderid) AND (tblleader.fk_userid = tbluser.userid);
```

Comment: it is missing the leader name in the result.

Comment: there is no leader name there is only username so we have to compare the fk_userid of tblleader with the userid of tbluser if they match you got your leader name :).
because a leader is also a user.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
table1
    INNER JOIN
tabel2 ON table2.id = table1.id
    INNER JOIN
table3 ON table3.id = table2.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample data might have helped you better here, But I think you can try the below query -

```
SELECT userid AS "Sl. No",
       username "Member Name",
       taskname "Task Name",
       taskstatus "Task Status",
       Leader Name
  FROM tbluser TU 
  JOIN tblmember TM ON TM.fk_userid = TU.userid
  JOIN tblleader TL ON TL.fk_userid = TU.userid
  JOIN tbltask TT ON TL.leaderid TT.fk_leaderid
                  AND TM.memberid = TT.fk_memberid;
```